# iOS XHR Cors issue when uploading multiple images

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, cors, ionic4

I have an ionic app (developed using ionic 4) where users can upload multiple images. It works fine on Android. However, on iOS, I have no problem when uploading only one image but when uploading multiple images, suddenly I got this error:

> ```
> Origin ionic://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load <the url i'm trying to reach> due to access control checks
> ```

My server has CORS enable through *[barryvdh/laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors/issues/336)*, therefore I do not understand why this happens. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than 200 OK success response?

Comment: @sideshowbarker seems like HttpErrorResponse code 0

Answer (score 0):

CORS error can be misleading. Turns out it was an issue with uploading file size bigger than allowed as specified in my server's php.ini and nginx configuration. Increasing the `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in `php.ini` and adding `client_max_body_size` in `nginx.conf` solved it.